# simplify following 4y+6x divided by xy

Tags: algebra-precalculus

simplify: 4y+6x/xy

I did 4y*xy = 4xy^2 and 6x^2y / xy
I then /xy = 4y+6x = (2) 2y+3x.
But this was not correct. Help in steps please.

Comment: Is $$4y+\frac{6x}{xy}$$ or $$\frac{4y+6x}{xy}$$??

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran I think its $$\frac{4y + 6x}{xy}$$ However I don't think it can simplified

Comment: @VarunIyer - It can be simplified, but it depends on what you call 'simplified'. Write it instead as
$$\frac{1}{xy}(4y + 6x)$$
and see what you get.

Comment: @SimonRose yes that is true, but he should indicate that in his question. Simplification is perceived as what the user think. Both forms can be seen as acceptable. Multiple forms are present

Comment: This is not correct according to the answer: 4x+6y

Answer (score 1):

> Use this:$$\dfrac{a\cdot b}{a}=b.$$
>
> ---
>
> $$\begin{equation}\begin{split}\dfrac{4y+6x}{xy}&=\dfrac{4y}{xy}+\dfrac{6x}{xy}\\&=\dfrac{4}{x}+\dfrac{6}{y}\end{split}\end{equation}$$